# Using MQTT to send 1 second batches

Tags: mqtt, paho

I want to send telemetry data from 3 cameras with MQTT. I will use AWS lambda to process data that comes from MQTT client (this forces me to use 1 second interval).

The problem is I want to send data in 1 seconds batches and I can't find a reliable way to avoid data loss. Basically I want to store 100+ messages that come in milliseconds apart and store them in my code, then send them as one MQTT message. My code so far is below and I'd appreciate any suggestions.

```py
while True:
    t_end = time.time() + 1
    payload={}
    while time.time() < t_end:
        data = response.fp.readline()
        if data.decode("utf-8")[:4]=="data":
            raw=data.decode("utf-8")[5:]
            payload.update(raw)

    myMQTTClient.publish(
        topic="home/helloworld",
        QoS=1,
        payload=json.dumps(payload))
```

Comment: So the code for batching the data is not really relevant. Do you have any insight into what's causing the losses? What is the environment? How significant are the losses? Have you tried sending data to 2 different brokers maybe?

Comment: You are likely to have issues running this without a [network loop](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python#network-loop) (the ACK packets will not be handled so you will run out of message IDs eventually). It's possible you have addressed this but cannot see in the fragment of code provided (a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help).